# PHP - Workaround undefined index for array

Tags: php

I'm trying to simply add +1 to an array like this

```
$game['teamA']['goals']++;
```

But then it'll throw me an error about undefined index. And I guess that's because `$game['teamA']['goals']` is not set before I am adding a value to it.

But isn't there a way to workaround this?

I could set the `$game['teamA']['goals'] = 0` in start of simulation, but then I have to do that with freekicks, penalties, cards etc., AND do it for both teams. Isn't there another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: so.. checking if it isset, if not add? Or is there a shorten way of using isset?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to test if it's already a number, before incrementing it?  Or are you asking if there's some way of convincing the compiler that all unknown values should be treated as 0?

Comment: @Sepster that all unknown values should be treated as 0 before incrementing.

Comment: @Kolind that would be asking for trouble.  Zero (in most cases - including yours, I'd say!) has meaning too.  So by confusing zero with "unknown" or "undefined", would ruin the meaning of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ALWAYS initialise variables before they are used. One way to do this would be:

```
$game = array('teamA' => 
                  array(
                      'goals' => 0,
                      'freekicks' => 0,
                      'penalties' => 0,
                      ....
                  ),
              'teamB' =>
                  array(
                      'goals' => 0,
                      'freekicks' => 0,
                      'penalties' => 0,
                      ...
                  )
              );
```

Comment: I will initialise them to begin win then. Seems this is proper way of doing it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you go with a "proper initialisation", as you suggested. That would some code to your program but it's always better then on each update to check. Better do

```
$game = array( 'teamA' => array('goals'       => 0,
                                'freekicks'   => 0,
                                'penalties'   => 0,
                                // etc ...                       
                          ),
               'teamB' => array('goals'       => 0,
                                'freekicks'   => 0,
                                'penalties'   => 0,
                                // etc ...
                          )
        );
```

instead of

```
if(isset($game['teamA']['goals']))
    $game['teamA']['goals']++;
else
    $game[teamA]['goals'] = 1;
```

There's nothing wrong to properly init your variables - all of them. It's even advisable to do so.

Comment: Thanks. But i'll initialise them in the beginning. I know. I agree on you :)

Answer (score 1):

write a wrapper function to set the values.

```
<?php

function increment(&$dict, $key1, $key2) {
  if (!isset($dict, $key1))
    $dict[$key1] = array();
  if (!isset($dict[$key1], $key2))
    $dict[$key1][$key2] = 1;
  else
    $dict[$key1][$key2] ++;
}

$game= array();
increment($game, "teamA", "goals");
var_dump( $game);
?>
```

It really depends on what you expect on the *runtime*; if these operations are called often, it would be better to create all array indices before doing anything else, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12873359/1689451 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Before incrementing, check for existence of the array, if not, create one! As simple as that. You can use a built-in function called [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), which checks the existence of the variable.

#### Short Way:

```
(isset($game['teamA']['goals']) ? $game['teamA']['goals']++ : $game['teamA']['goals'] = 1;
```

#### Or using `if` condition:

```
if (isset($game['teamA']['goals'])
    $game['teamA']['goals']++;
else
    $game['teamA']['goals'] = 1;
```

Comment: I know isset() exists. But did not know the shorten version of an if-sentence. I'll use that. I was looking for something as short as possible.

Comment: Once again - better initialise them in the beginning.

Comment: This is the best shorter way possible. Try it out, else I will try to get more shorter way.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen but I will initialise my $game array in the beginning of my script.